# Error: processing respone error, Transaction reverted without a reason

Tags: solidity, error

### I have a simple counter and it charges a fee everytime:

### But it throws an error:

Error: processing response error (body="{"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":48,"error":{"code":-32603,"message":"Error: Transaction reverted without a reason string"}}", error={"code":-32603}, requestBody="{"method":"eth_estimateGas","params":[{"from":"0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266","to":"0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3","data":"0xd09de08a"}],"id":48,"jsonrpc":"2.0"}", requestMethod="POST", url="http://localhost:8545", code=SERVER_ERROR, version=web/5.4.0)

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: Unlicense
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Counter {
    uint256 public count;

    address public Owner;

    event Increment(uint256 value);
    event Decrement(uint256 value);

    constructor() public {
        count = 0;
    }

    function getCount() public view returns (uint256 count) {
        return count;
    }

    function increment() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 10);
        count += 1;
        emit Increment(count);
    }

    function decrement() public payable {
        require(msg.value > 100);
        count -= 1;
        emit Decrement(count);
    }
}
```

Front End:

```
const [count, setCount] = useState()

  useEffect(() => {
    loadCount()
    setInterval(() => { loadCount() }, 2000)
  }, [])

  async function loadCount() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const counterContract = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", Counter.abi, provider)

    const count = await counterContract.getCount()

    console.log(await count.toString())
    setCount(await count.toString())
  }

  async function increment() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const counterContract = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", Counter.abi, signer)

    await counterContract.increment()

    loadCount()
  }

  async function decrement() {
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider()
    const signer = provider.getSigner()
    const counterContract = new ethers.Contract("0x5FbDB2315678afecb367f032d93F642f64180aa3", Counter.abi, signer)

    await counterContract.decrement()

    loadCount()
  }

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Counter" />
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <h2 className="">{count}</h2>
      <button onClick={() => increment()}>INCREMENT</button>
      <button onClick={() => decrement()}>DECREMENT</button>
    </div>
  )
```

Comment: How are u calling those functions ? Using remix!?

Comment: No I have a frontend

Comment: Are you sending value with the transaction? You can try it on remix and if it works then ur Frontend call is the error

Comment: maybe show frontend code cause the contract look correct

Comment: Ok updated it. I will try it on remix

Comment: I get an error: The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.

Comment: In ur frontend code u are not sending ether(fee) with ur transaction. You need to add value to ur transaction

Comment: To make the debugging easier add revert message require(msg.value > 100, „low message value“)

Comment: To send ether with ur contract call you need to modify ur call -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68049580/how-to-invoke-a-payable-solidity-function-using-hardhat

Comment: In my forth comment I didn’t mean the transaction fee (that will be taken automatically) I mean your extra fee, u should add that explicitly to the tx

Comment: How do i do that?

Comment: Try this: await counterContract.increment({value: ethers.utils.parseEther(„1.0“)});

Comment: U will send one ether , change the amount to the amount u need or use another method like ethers.utils.parseUnits(„1.0“, „ether“)

Comment: It works like the eth is going out of the account but the counter dosn't count up

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably from the variable count being use in a return statement and a global variable.

```
uint256 public count;


function getCount() public view returns (uint256 count) {
        return count;
    }
```

First you don't need this getCount function, By declaring count as public, solidity create a getter function for count. You can use `count()` and it will return the value.

Just remove that function.

and in the front end call for `count()`

```
const count = await counterContract.count()
```

Same result, Should not trow an error, and you just saved some gas on deployment.

Answer (score 0):

> require(msg.value > 10);

You have condition for value to be send while calling the function increament as well as for decrement and you are not sending any eth while calling the function.
At the same time you had not added revert message. This might be the reason for failing the contract function call.